# How to connect to Istio api from kubernetes java client and retrive virtual services?

Tags: java, kubernetes, istio

I'm trying to list already existing Virtual Services from Istio using [istio-java-api](https://github.com/snowdrop/istio-java-api) and [java-kubernetes-client](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java). Isto-java-api only describes how to create resoruces on Istio. How would you retrive those same resoruces?